# In a mobile app, what is a good approach to get updates from the backend?

Tags: flutter, mobile, architecture, synchronization

I am writing an app with Flutter, and I am trying to figure out what the best way to receive update from the backend is.

I thought of using two timestamps, a `backwardTimestamp` the following docstring:

```
  /// [backwardTimestamp] is the `<` in the following timeline.
  ///
  /// `|` initially represents both [forwardTimestamp] and [backwardTimestamp]
  /// (which hold the same value), the first time of the user session on the current device
  ///
  /// (i.e., point in time) when the app was used (NB: there is data to fetch from the server).
  ///
  /// - Before very first synchronization:
  ///   - old content `----------------------------< | >` new content
  /// - During synchronization:
  ///   - old content `---<------------------------- | >` new content
  /// - After synchronization (it becomes null):
  ///   - old content `||--------------------------- | >` new content
```

and a `forwardTimestamp`, whose docstring is

```
  /// [forwardTimestamp] is the `>` in the following timeline.
  ///
  /// `|` initially represents the last [forwardTimestamp] (i.e., point in time) when the associated
  /// user fetched synchronized data with the server.
  ///
  /// - Before synchronization:
  ///   - old content `||--------------------------- | >-----------` new content
  /// - During synchronization:
  ///   - old content `||--------------------------- | -------->---` new content
  /// - After synchronization (unlike [backwardTimestamp], it never becomes null):
  ///   - old content `||--------------------------- | ----------->` new content
```

The idea here is to receive the most recent data first, so once the user is logged in they can already view some of the content. If I were to use only a `forwardTimestamp` (thus, no `backwardTimestamp`) which starts e.g. at year 1970, then the data displayed would constantly change (newer content is constantly added) and users may have to wait several minutes before they can see the newest content, which I do not find very user friendly. This is why for the first sync `backwardTimestamp` is leveraged.

With the double timestamp strategy i was thinking to add time metadata for every piece of data (e.g. the fields of a Photo object would be `photoUrl` "coupled" with `photoUrlLastUpdated`, `photoDescription` "coupled" with `photoDescriptionLastUpdated`. and so on...). This way, it is possible to make sure older things do not override newer ones.

An issues that I see with this approach might be that if I did not use the app for e.g. 6 months, and when I open it again there are lots of updates, it might take several minutes to display the most recent ones due to `forwardTimestamp` fetching the 6-month-old updates first...

In general, I am a bit skeptical about this architecture, and I would love to hear your feedback. Maybe this could be better solved with hashes or some other approach instead of timestamps? Also, since I do not need to rollback to a previous point in time, I think the double timestamp approach might be a bit excessive. Can you think of a better approach for this problem? Note that all backend updates will be merged/inserted into a device-local database, so the app can also be used offline.

Thanks in advance!